# Why won't dynamically adding a `__call__` method to an instance work?

Tags: python, instance

In both Python 2 and Python 3 the code:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

f = Foo()
f.__call__ = lambda *args : args

f(1, 2, 3)
```

returns as error `Foo object is not callable`. Why does that happen?

PS: With old-style classes it works as expected.

PPS: This behavior is intended (see accepted answer). As a work-around it's possible to define a `__call__` at class level that just forwards to another member and set this "normal" member to a per-instance `__call__` implementation.

```
Python 3.10.8 (main, Nov  1 2022, 14:18:21) [GCC 12.2.0]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.7.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: class Foo:
   ...:     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   ...:         return self.call(*args, **kwargs)
   ...: 

In [2]: f = Foo()

In [3]: f.call = lambda *args, **kwargs: (args, kwargs)

In [4]: f(1,2,3)
Out[4]: ((1, 2, 3), {})
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Double-underscore methods are always looked up on the class, never the instance. See [*Special method lookup for new-style classes*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes):

> For new-style classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary.

That's because the *type* might need to support the same operation (in which case the special method is looked up on the metatype).

For example, classes are callable (that's how you produce an instance), but if Python looked up the `__call__` method *on the actual object*, then you could never do so on classes that implement `__call__` for their instances. `ClassObject()` would become `ClassObject.__call__()` which would fail because the `self` parameter is not passed in to the unbound method. So instead `type(ClassObject).__call__(ClassObject)` is used, and calling `instance()` translates to `type(instance).__call__(instance)`.

To work around this, you could add a `__call__` method to the class which checks for a `__call__` attribute on the class, and if there, calls it.

Comment: To define a per-instance `__call__` implementation I'm currently using a class-level `__call__` that forwards to a regular member. Seems an ugly solution however...

Comment: @6502: that's the recommended work-around. If you really need to delegate to a per-instance callable, then doing so explicitly in a class-level `__call__` is the best way to do so.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What would be a work around to forward all operators (`__add__`, `__rtruediv__`, etc) to an integer object store inside the proxy? I'd like to not implement all methods manually if possible.

Comment: @danijar: you could use a metaclass to generate the methods from a list of names perhaps.

Answer (score 4):

In new style classes (default `3.x`) and inherited from object in `2.x` the attribute interception methods `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` [are no longer called for built-in operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes) on dunder overloaded methods of instances and instead the search begins at the class.

The rationale behind this, involves a technicallity introduced by the presence of MetaClasses.

Because classes are instances of metaclasses and because metaclasses might define certain operations that act on classes, skipping the class (which in this case can be considered an `instance`) makes sense; you need to invoke the method defined in the metaclass which is defined to process classes (`cls` as a first argument). If instance look-up was used, the look-up would use the class method which is defined for instances of that class (`self`).

Another (*disputed* reason) involves *optimization*: Since built-in operations on instances are usually invoked **very** frequently, skipping the instance look-up altogether and going directly to the class saves us some time. [*Source Lutz, Learning Python, 5th Edition*]

---

The **main area** where this might be of inconvenience is when creating proxy objects that overload `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` with intent to forward the calls to the embedded internal object. Since built-in invocation will skip the instance altogether they won't get caught and as an effect won't get forwarded to the embedded object.

An easy, but tedious, work-around for this is to actually overload all the dunders you wish to intercept in the proxy object. Then in these overloaded dunders you can delegate the call to the internal object as required.

---

The easiest work-around I can think of is setting the attribute on the class `Foo` with `setattr`:

```
setattr(Foo, '__call__', lambda *args: print(args))

f(1, 2, 3)
(<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f40640faa90>, 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: You are confusing matters here. Python bypasses `__getattribute__` in some cases as an optimisation. But looking up special methods on the class is not an optimisation choice; it is needed to properly support special methods acting *on the type*. Compare `hash(int)` with `hash(1)`, for example, both need to be supported.

Comment: I added that as a second reason; but couldn't this *also* be considered for optimization since in cases where we have **many** instances of a given class we skip the `__dict__` look-up in the new model?

Comment: That lookup is cheap, and when calling a special method on an instance, *there is just one instance*.

Comment: For more info see the documentation I linked to in my answer. You presented the optimisation as the first reason.

Comment: I switched the ordering and added a nice disputed to it (and a source of where I found it). Might test it out and come back asking questions. Thanks for the insights.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't understand why these methods have to act on the type as well. Why do both `hash(int)` and `hash(1)` have to be supported? If the programmer attaches the method after instantiation, isn't it fair to assume that they were fully aware that `hash(type(foo))` wouldn't work? Otherwise, they could've simply attached the method to the type itself, consciously... what am I missing?

Comment: @Nearoo: how else would you be able to use types as dictionary keys? `dispatch = {int: function_to_handle_integers, float: function_to_handle_floats}`. If `__hash__` was looked up on the instance, then you'd get `int.__hash__()` being called and failing because it's not bound to an actual integer. Instead `type.__hash__(int)` is called, and for actual integers like `1`, `int.__hash__(1)` is  called. In other words, this matters because types (classes) are objects *too*, they are instances of `type`.