# How can I dynamically call built in methods such as __doc__ in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and I was printing the `__doc__` of various built-in Python methods. Then I tried to do the following:

```
for f in dir(__builtins__):
    print('********' + f + '********\n', f.__doc__)
```

I was surprised when the result of this looked something like this:

```
********abs********
    str(object='') -> str
    str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str
********all********
    str(object='') -> str
    str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str
********any********
    str(object='') -> str
    str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str
********ascii********
    str(object='') -> str
    str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str
```

After doing some research, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824228/why-wont-dynamically-adding-a-call-method-to-an-instance-work), but I still didn't see how I could do what I was hoping to accomplish. I know that this is seamlingly pointless, but I feel it will be useful for me to understand how to dynamically execute tasks similar to this in Python.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dir(__builtins__)` (also iterating over a module) gives the names in the module to get the objects one has to use `getattr`:

```
for f in dir(__builtins__):
    print('********' + f + '********\n', getattr(__builtins__, f).__doc__)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop, you are not getting the actual functions/methods when you call

```
for f in dir(__builtins__):
```

Instead, each time `f` is just a string with the name of the function/method.  So when you call:

```
f.__doc__
```

You are always getting back the docstring for `str` types.  It is no different than calling:

```
'abc'.__doc__
```