Python hooks methods at runtime
Is there a way for Python to hook specified methods at runtime, similar to Java's bytebuddy framework, to modify bytecode at runtime,
For example, there is the following code
def method(str):
    print(str)
    
def new_method(originMethod):
    print("new_method")
    originMethod.method()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    set_hook(method,new_method)
    
    method("a")

I want his final output to be as follows
new_method
a

Sometimes I can't directly reference the address of a method. I want to hook it through the function name, is it possible.
class User:
def method(self):
print("")
        

def method(str):
print(str)


def new_method(originMethod):
print("new_method")
originMethod.method()


def setting_hook(original_method, hook_method):
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
hook_method(original_method, *args, **kwargs)

return wrapper


if __name__ == '__main__':
setting_hook("User.method", new_method)
setting_hook("method", new_method)

I don't want to use decorators because they cannot be modified at runtime

Classes can just be changed, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4408225/1319284
They are basically just dictionaries. And so are modules.
Below code is tested with Python 3.11
class User:
  def method(self):
    print("")

def method(str):
  print(str)
        

def wrap(originMethod):
  def new_method(*args, **keywords):
    print("new_method")
    originMethod(*args, **keywords)
  return new_method

if __name__ == '__main__':
  User.method = wrap(User.method)
  method = wrap(method)
  method("hello")
  user = User()
  user.method()

  

If you want to use strings, that also works on classes with __getattr__ and __setattr__ but modules are more complicated, see this question.

You can try this:
def method(str):
    print(str)

def new_method(ori_method, *args, **kwargs):
    print("new_method")
    ori_method(*args, **kwargs)

def setting_hook(original_method, hook_method):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        hook_method(original_method, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

if __name__ == '__main__':
method
    hooked_method = setting_hook(method, new_method)
    method = hooked_method
    method("a")


Thank you for your reply.Sometimes I can't directly reference the address of a method. I want to hook it through the function name, is it possible.

In Python, you can dynamically modify how a function behaves by passing it through another function that acts as a "hook". Functions are first-class citizens. This means they can be passed around as arguments to other functions, returned from functions, and assigned to variables.

How can I obtain the address of a function through its name and modify the address of the original function in the module
